# Why isn't the array displaying in the textarea?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, dom

What I am basically trying to do, is split a string given my by the user, and place it in a textarea. The problem however is that, each time i click the convert button, both input field and textarea gets cleared.
Never mind the additional statements.

Here is the html code

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Latin Converter</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="p14.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Enter a sentence:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" size="40" id="userinput" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button id="convert">Convert to Pig Latin</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Converter</td>
                    <td>
                        <textarea id="result" cols="40" rows="20"></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's my js code:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var convertArray = document.getElementById("convert");
    convertArray.addEventListener('click', printLatinWord);
};

function printLatinWord() {
        var input = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
        var array = input.split(" ");
        var firstChar = array.shift();
        array.push(firstChar);
        document.getElementById("result").value = array;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a form and the button inside, button inside form is by default considered as submit button, so when you click the form submited and the page refresh so the fields cleared.

I suggest to add `type='button'` to the `button` like following :

```
<button type='button' id="convert">
```

---

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var convertArray = document.getElementById("convert");
    convertArray.addEventListener('click', printLatinWord);
};

function printLatinWord() {
        var input = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
        var array = input.split(" ");
        var firstChar = array.shift();
        array.push(firstChar);
        document.getElementById("result").value = array;
}
```

```html
<form>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Enter a sentence:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" size="40" id="userinput" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button type='button' id="convert">Convert to Pig Latin</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Converter</td>
                    <td>
                        <textarea id="result" cols="40" rows="20"></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: is there anyway to keep the form?

Comment: @Predator44, Also be mindful that it is more careful to convert your JS object/array to a string before outputting it. If it were an object, the contents of your object wouldn't be printed, you'd get `[object Object]`

Comment: @Tyblitz noted. Thank you